# save the output to a file using here

Tags: shell, scripting

I am doing ssh to one of my network devices and want to save command output in a file . How can I do it using here command .

`var=$( ssh usr@dev "command")`  not working on the device so I have to use here function

```
ssh usr@dev <<EOF
command
EOF
```

however , above command is working . Can I save this output into a file ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the '>>' operator. It appends the output of the command to the end of the file. You can use it like this:

```
who | grep username >> user.txt
```

If the result is just a string, echo can help you:

```
result='success'
echo $result >> result.txt
```